# How to set OpenStack API configuration in Centos 7?

Tags: openstack

Please tell me which SDK is better to call OpenStack APIs.

I haven't found much information or tutorials on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CLI; the official Openstack client is the obvious choice. If you are trying to make programmatic API calls you can use anything from simple http request to a client library like [shade](https://github.com/openstack-infra/shade) for Python, or [gophercloud](https://github.com/gophercloud/gophercloud) for Golang.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install openstacksdk
```

Conneect to the cloud:

```
    """
Connect to an OpenStack cloud.

For a full guide see TODO(etoews):link to docs on developer.openstack.org
"""

import argparse
import os

import openstack
from openstack.config import loader
import sys

openstack.enable_logging(True, stream=sys.stdout)

#: Defines the OpenStack Config loud key in your config file,
#: typically in $HOME/.config/openstack/clouds.yaml. That configuration
#: will determine where the examples will be run and what resource defaults
#: will be used to run the examples.
TEST_CLOUD = os.getenv('OS_TEST_CLOUD', 'devstack-admin')
config = loader.OpenStackConfig()
cloud = openstack.connect(cloud=TEST_CLOUD)


class Opts(object):
    def __init__(self, cloud_name='devstack-admin', debug=False):
        self.cloud = cloud_name
        self.debug = debug
        # Use identity v3 API for examples.
        self.identity_api_version = '3'


def _get_resource_value(resource_key, default):
    return config.get_extra_config('example').get(resource_key, default)

SERVER_NAME = 'openstacksdk-example'
IMAGE_NAME = _get_resource_value('image_name', 'cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk')
FLAVOR_NAME = _get_resource_value('flavor_name', 'm1.small')
NETWORK_NAME = _get_resource_value('network_name', 'private')
KEYPAIR_NAME = _get_resource_value('keypair_name', 'openstacksdk-example')
SSH_DIR = _get_resource_value(
    'ssh_dir', '{home}/.ssh'.format(home=os.path.expanduser("~")))
PRIVATE_KEYPAIR_FILE = _get_resource_value(
    'private_keypair_file', '{ssh_dir}/id_rsa.{key}'.format(
        ssh_dir=SSH_DIR, key=KEYPAIR_NAME))

EXAMPLE_IMAGE_NAME = 'openstacksdk-example-public-image'


def create_connection_from_config():
    return openstack.connect(cloud=TEST_CLOUD)


def create_connection_from_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    config = loader.OpenStackConfig()
    config.register_argparse_arguments(parser, sys.argv[1:])
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return openstack.connect(config=config.get_one(argparse=args))


def create_connection(auth_url, region, project_name, username, password):

    return openstack.connect(
        auth_url=auth_url,
        project_name=project_name,
        username=username,
        password=password,
        region_name=region,
        app_name='examples',
        app_version='1.0',
    )
```

[Complete guide](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/)

Comment: is this python code? Can you guide me how to develop API's to call identity api and other API's one after other from external server.

Comment: yes , you can see that this is python code , for more dertails see the complete guide link give. thanks

Comment: I am using openstack in separate vm and i am trying to call those openstack services through API calls from local host how to do this please help me

Comment: It doesn't matter in which vm you are running opstack, just put the URL , user and password in client configuration